# Как разделить строку по числу или цифре

Tags: c#

Есть строка с предложением, например `"В неделе 7 дней"`. Как разделить строку по этой цифре на `"В неделе "` и `" дней"` если за ранее не известно какая это будет цифра?
Хотел попробовать через `.Split()`, но не понятно что должно быть в скобках.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод Split принимает так же массив, каждый элемент которого, порежет строчку.

если у вас в тексте встречаются только цифры до 10, то можно так :

```
var input = "В неделе 7 дней";
var t1 = input.Split("0123456789".ToCharArray());
```

если же могут встетиться любые числа, то лучше использовать Regex :

```
var input = "В неделе 7 дней";
var t2 = Regex.Split(input, "-?[0-9]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно разделить по регулярному выражению [`Regex.Split`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.7.2), где вторым параметром можно передать регулярку.

Вот [тут](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split) даже пример есть как раз по вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = "В неделе 7 дней";
var firstDigitValue = date.FirstOrDefault(x => Char.IsDigit(x));
var lastDigitValue = date.LastOrDefault(x => Char.IsDigit(x));
var weekPart = date.Substring(0, firstDigitValue);
var dayPart = date.Substring(lastDigitValue, date.Length);
```

Уверен что это далеко не лучший результат но думаю что так должно сработать.